# TFS User Story - All Links, change selected columns for LinksControlOptionsType

Tags: tfs, workitem

Changing the selected columns for the LinksControlOptionsType for my User Story Work Item, it does not reflect the changes I make. I've added columns and changed the order of the columns.

[image: Control Settings]

Both columns and order are different in the actual view.
[image: TFS Web]

When I access the work item using visual studio, the changes are present, but not while using the tfs web interface.

Comment: are you editing the right link control and did you re-upload your changed witd to the server?

Comment: Yes, the changes are uploaded. I've verified that the changes are present when I do a open from server. I also changed the label on the tabpage containing the control, to verify that I am editing the correct work item / control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Name property of the Control does the trick. There might be a hardcoded query of the name GeneralLinks. Choosing another name, and the changes in the LinkControlOptionsType is displayed.